# Can't enable Coherence Mode in Parallels 12

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, parallels

I've tried everything. Coherence Mode is greyed out in Parallels 12 for Windows 10.

- I do not have an antivirus. (http://kb.parallels.com/en/121427)
- There are no other display adapters besides the Parallels Display Adapter (WDDM) that are installed.
- Parallels tools are installed properly. I've tried re-installing parallels tools in every manner outlined here: http://kb.parallels.com/112609

My setup:
 - I'm using a Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter to hook up to a 30" monitor.
 - Unplugging it doesn't allow Coherence Mode either.

Thanks for any help!

-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:
1. Click Parallel Desktop (the || sign)--> View --> Unclick Full Screen Mode
2. The Virtual Machine should now reside in a smaller window.
3. Click Parallels Desktop again and the "Enter Coherence Mode" option should work now.

Hope it helps!

ps1. Have tried exactly the same sequence as you did but it turned out that all installations are actually ok and it's just about getting familiar with how Parallels Desktop works.

ps2. Once entering coherence mode, you'll also be able to open Windows APPs directly under Mac as if they were Mac APPs. Before that if you open these Windows APP they will first switch to full screen Win 10 and then open the Windows APP within Win 10.

Comment: The annoying bit is that on my previous Win 10 VM i was able to switch between Coherence and Full Screen without going through the window.